# How to get timestamp for date column in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having a table name called "users". It has one column named "logondt" in which it will show only in this format `mm:dd:yy` like `04-JUN-14`.
But I need to use select query to find in which time, the user is logged in.

I tried something like this..

```
select logondt from users where logondt between to_date('2014-06-03' ,'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2014-06-03' ,'yyyy-mm-dd') and userid='12345';
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use **TO_CHAR** function

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(LOGONDT , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') LOGONDT 
FROM USERS
WHERE 
LOGONDT BETWEEN to_date('2014-06-03' ,'yyyy-mm-dd') 
        and to_date('2014-06-03' ,'yyyy-mm-dd') 
AND USERID = '12345';
```

To Get in 24 HR format,
use

```
TO_CHAR(LOGONDT , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: One more help, How can I find whether it is AM or PM ?

Comment: select to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') from dual;  This will work for both AM and PM.